# Expanding columns associated with a categorical variable into multiple columns with dplyr/tidyr while retaining id variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
dfTall <- frame_data(
    ~id, ~x, ~y, ~z,
      1, "a", 4, 5,
      1, "b", 6, 5,
      2, "a", 5, 4,
      2, "b", 1, 9)
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
dfWide <- frame_data(
    ~id, ~y_a, ~y_b, ~z_a, ~z_b,
      1,    4,    6,    5,    5,
      2,    5,    1,    4,    9)
```

Currently, I'm doing this

```
dfTall %>%
    split(., .$x) %>%
    mapply(function(df,name) 
        {df$x <- NULL; names(df) <- paste(names(df), name, sep='_'); df}, 
        SIMPLIFY=FALSE, ., names(.)) %>%
    bind_cols() %>%
    select(-id_b) %>%
    rename(id = id_a)
```

In practice, I will have a larger number of numeric columns that need to be expanded (i.e., not just `y` and `z`). My current solution works, but it has issues, like the fact that multiple copies of the `id` variable get added into the final `data.frame` and need to be removed.

Can this expansion be done using a function from `tidyr` such as `spread`?

Comment: Side note. I think `tribble` is the more up to date term for `frame_data`. See `?frame_data` details: "frame_data() is an older name for tribble(). It will eventually be phased out."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with `spread` but not in a single step, as it involves multiple columns as values; You can firstly `gather` the value columns, `unite` the headers manually and then `spread`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfTall %>% 
    gather(col, val, -id, -x) %>% 
    unite(key, col, x) %>% 
    spread(key, val)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#     id   y_a   y_b   z_a   z_b
#* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4     6     5     5
#2     2     5     1     4     9
```

---

If you use `data.table`, `dcast` supports cast multiple value columns:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dfTall), id ~ x, value.var = c('y', 'z'))

#   id y_a y_b z_a z_b
#1:  1   4   6   5   5
#2:  2   5   1   4   9
```

Comment: And base R is `reshape(as.data.frame(dfTall), idvar="id", timevar="x", direction="wide", sep="_")` as `reshape` also deals with multiple variables.