# How can we apply tidyr:: spread() to all categorical variables at once creating new columns for each level of each categorical variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with 3 categorical variables (`x`,`y`,`z`) along with an `ID` column :

```
df <- frame_data(
  ~id, ~x, ~y, ~z,
  1, "a", "c" ,"v",
  1, "b", "d", "f",
  2, "a", "d", "v",
  2, "b", "d", "v")
```

I want to apply `spread()` to each of the categorical variables group by `ID` .

Output should be like this :

```
id  a  b  c  d  v  f
1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  0  2  2  0
```

I tried doing it but I was able to do it only for one variable at once not all together .

For e.g: Applying spread only to the `y` column (similarly , it can be done for `x` and `z` separately) but not together in a single line

```
df %>% count(id,y) %>% spread(y,n,fill=0)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
id     c     d
<dbl> <int> <int>
1.00     1     1
2.00     0     2
```

Explaining my codes in three steps:

Step 1: count frequency

```
df %>% count(id,y)    
id     y         n
<dbl> <chr> <int>
1.00   c     1
1.00   d     1
2.00   d     2
```

Step 2 : applying `spread()`

```
df %>% count(id,y) %>% spread(y,n)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
id     c     d
<dbl> <int> <int>
1  1.00     1     1
2  2.00    NA     2
```

Step 3: Adding `fill = 0` , replaces `NA` which means there was zero occurrence of `c` in y column for `id 2` (as you can see in df)

```
df %>% count(id,y) %>% spread(y,n,fill=0)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
id     c     d
<dbl> <int> <int>
1.00     1     1
2.00     0     2
```

**Problem :** In my actual data set , I have 20 such categorical variables , I can't do it one by one for all. I am looking to do it all at once.
Is it possible apply `spread()` in `tidyr` for all of categorical variables all together ? If not can you please suggest an alternative

Note: I also gave a try to these answers but were not helpful for this particular case:

- [R spreading multiple columns with tidyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592094/r-spreading-multiple-columns-with-tidyr)
- [Is it possible to use spread on multiple columns in tidyr similar to dcast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929954/is-it-possible-to-use-spread-on-multiple-columns-in-tidyr-similar-to-dcast)
- [Can spread() in tidyr spread across multiple value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103882/can-spread-in-tidyr-spread-across-multiple-value)
- [Expanding columns associated with a categorical variable into multiple columns with dplyr/tidyr while retaining id variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872076/expanding-columns-associated-with-a-categorical-variable-into-multiple-columns-w)

**Additional related helpful question :**

It is possible that two categorical columns (Eg: Survey dataset) have same values . Like below.

```
df <- frame_data(
  ~id, ~Do_you_Watch_TV, ~Do_you_Drive, 
  1, "yes", "yes",
  1, "yes", "no",
  2, "yes", "no",
  2, "no", "yes")

# A tibble: 4 x 3
id Do_you_Watch_TV Do_you_Drive
<dbl> <chr>           <chr>       
  1  1.00 yes             yes         
2  1.00 yes             no          
3  2.00 yes             no          
4  2.00 no              yes
```

Running the below code would not differentiate counts of yes and no for 'Do_you_Watch_TV', 'Do_you_Drive' :

```
df %>% gather(Key, value, -id) %>% 
  group_by(id, value) %>%
  summarise(count = n())  %>%
  spread(value, count, fill = 0) %>%
  as.data.frame()
id no yes
1  1   3
2  2   2

Whereas, expected output should be :
id Do_you_Watch_TV_no   Do_you_Watch_TV_yes  Do_you_Drive_no   Do_you_Drive_yes
1         0               2                    1                 1
2         1               1                    1                 1
```

So , we need to treat No and Yes from Do_you_Watch_TV and Do_you_Drive  separately by adding prefix. Do_you_Drive_yes , Do_you_Drive_no , Do_you_Watch_TV _yes, Do_you_Watch_TV _no .

How can we achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jaap : The question above has two parts. 
**The first part is answered partly by you here** : [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262085/using-group-by-create-aggregated-counts-conditional-on-value . Your code suggests to mention columns explicitly within gather : 
`tidyr :: spread library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  gather(key, val, state:type2) %>% 
  group_by(serialno, val) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  spread(val, n, fill = 0)`
Whereas I am looking for doing it implicitly.
So,Instead of `gather(Key, value,  state:type2)`  , we can use `gather(Key, value,  -serialno)`

Comment: @JAAP 
**The second part is : How do we do the same if we have an added condition - if two different category columns have same value ?**
The answer to it is also not here [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262085/using-group-by-create-aggregated-counts-conditional-on-value . So, this question is possibly not a duplicate.

Both parts have been answered  below

Comment: Thanks for adding second link , but does that cover using `tidyr::spread()` ? Can you add the link here if any ?
The first link is partially asnwered . Second link : uses `dcast()`
My question is related using `tidyr::spread()` as it performs better than `dcast()` (time of execution) . Kindly review my title and question asked

Comment: (1) The first link answer the first part of your question fully. `gather(Key, value, state:type2)` is the same as `gather(Key, value, -serialno)`, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25856135/2204410). (2) The two additional links cover the second part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert your data frame in long format before you can actually transform it in wide format. Hence, first you need to use `tidyr::gather` and convert data frame to long format. Afterwards, you have couple of options:

**Option#1:** Using `tidyr::spread`:

```
#data
df <- frame_data(
  ~id, ~x, ~y, ~z,
  1, "a", "c" ,"v",
  1, "b", "d", "f",
  2, "a", "d", "v",
  2, "b", "d", "v")

library(tidyverse)
df %>% gather(Key, value, -id) %>% 
  group_by(id, value) %>%
  summarise(count = n())  %>%
  spread(value, count, fill = 0) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   id a b c d f v
# 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 2  2 1 1 0 2 0 2
```

**Option#2:** Another option can be is to use `reshape2::dcast` as:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

df %>% gather(Key, value, -id) %>% 
  dcast(id~value, fun.aggregate = length)

#   id a b c d f v
# 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 2  2 1 1 0 2 0 2
```

**Edited:** To include solution for 2nd data frame.

```
#Data
df1 <- frame_data(
  ~id, ~Do_you_Watch_TV, ~Do_you_Drive, 
  1, "yes", "yes",
  1, "yes", "no",
  2, "yes", "no",
  2, "no", "yes")

library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% gather(Key, value, -id) %>% unite("value", c(Key, value)) %>%
  group_by(id, value) %>%
  summarise(count = n())  %>%
  spread(value, count, fill = 0) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   id Do_you_Drive_no Do_you_Drive_yes Do_you_Watch_TV_no Do_you_Watch_TV_yes
# 1  1               1                1                  0                   2
# 2  2               1                1                  1                   1
```

Comment: if not using `spread` is allowed, option#3: `df %>% gather(var, val, x:z) %>% {xtabs(~ id + val, data = .)}` and ... .

Comment: @mt1022 - option# 3 works  but we need to specify column names explicitly like x:z . For implicit way of doing , I would prefer going with option#1 or #2

Comment: @Ravijeet, agreed. The key message is that we can achieve the desired output with many alternative ways that are simpler than `spread`-based approach.

Comment: @MKR - That works. But, I have one more related question : how can we add prefix (parent column i.e. x_) to a , b  , c ?  It becomes x_a ,x_b,x_c .
I just realized there can be two categorical columns with same levels . Eg: x having levels 'Yes' and 'No' and y also having 'Yes' and 'No' . So , we need to treat them separately by adding prefix. x_yes , x_no , y_yes, y_no

Comment: @Ravijeet You can create columns as `x_a`, `x_b` etc. You need to add `unite("value", c(Key, value)) %>%` before `group_by` in option#1. But I really dont understand what you mean by `Yes` and `No` part. It would be better to add and small example for expected output.

Comment: @MKR : Added the example and expected output  in the question.  `unite("value", c(Key, value))`  - Works  to take care of this related question too . Thanks